# Make excel print multiple worksheets in a single print job

Tags: c++, excel, com, printing, office-automation

I'm using COM automation to open a xls file and print it to a virtual PDF printer.

```
Sheets sheets(m_Application.GetSheets());
sheets.PrintOut(CovOptional,CovOptional,CovOptional,CovOptional,COleVariant(_T("My PDF Printer")),CovOptional,CovOptional);
```

If the file has multiple worksheets, however, excel creates a separate print job for every sheet, so I get several PDF files instead of one.

How can I force it to print all the sheets in a single print job?

Comment: Excel 2007 and on can create PDF output directly, so try recording a macro while doing that and use that as a starting point.  If you select multiple sheets before saving as PDF it will put them all in a single file.

Comment: The application is not for in-house use, unfortunately. It needs to support at least Office 2003, many people are still using it.

Comment: Does the 'Sheets' class actually give you the ability to print multiple sheets in one job? If not you'll need to inherit the class into a custom class and add a custom method. If yes then are you using the right method? If so are your arguments in that method correct?

Comment: @satuon - Based on your edit, you could print twice (first to the MS image printer) and just delete the first document.

Comment: If I go that route, I would be better off just merging the PDF files after they are created. I'm thinking of doing just that, if I can't find a way to force Excel to print in a single job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a very good explanation for why Excel has this behavior [in this article](http://www.tracker-software.com/knowledgebase/185-How-do-I-make-Excel-print-several-sheets-in-a-single-PDF). From the article

> This happens because of the way Microsoft Excel sends the print job.
>   Excel assumes that all your individual sheets have different page
>   setups, so it sends them as multiple print-jobs.
>
> In order to have all the individual sheets printed within a single PDF
>   file (not multiple PDFs) you need to set the same page setup options
>   for all of them (page setup in Excel modifies the print size of the
>   resulting file, so for example if you set the page layout to landscape
>   in Excel, the printed page will be landscape but your original Excel
>   file will still maintain the same view).

I adapted code from [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10538627/492336) to a similar question. The code was originally in C# but I adapted it to C++.

```
Sheets sheets(m_Application.GetSheets());

for (int ii = 1; ii <= sheets.GetCount(); ii++)
{
    _Worksheet sheet(sheets.GetItem(COleVariant((long) ii)));
    PageSetup pagesetup(sheet.GetPageSetup());
    pagesetup.SetOrientation(2); // landscape
    pagesetup.SetOrder(1); // xlDownThenOver
    pagesetup.SetFitToPagesWide(COleVariant((long) 1));
    pagesetup.SetFitToPagesTall(COleVariant((long) 50));
    VARIANT variant;
    variant.vt = VT_BOOL;
    variant.boolVal = VARIANT_FALSE;
    pagesetup.SetZoom(variant);
}

sheets.PrintOut(CovOptional, CovOptional, CovOptional, CovOptional, COleVariant(_T(MyAppPrinterName)), CovOptional, CovOptional);
```